# Python: How can i copy files and do a rollback if it fails

Tags: python, file, copy, rollback

i have two similar directories (same structure) A and B. And i want to replace the files from directory A with the files from directory B. 
However i want the possibility to do a rollback and keep everything as it was at the beginning if something fails.

How would you do this (with Python)?

Answer (score 0):

File I/O operations are OS based and are not prone to rollback operations, however you can do variety of checks before performing an operations like:

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile(filepath)
    # file exists

if my_file.is_dir():
    # directory exists 

if my_file.exists():
    # path exists
```

for rollback operations you can try to store the files you copied into list and on exception delete everything from that list